# DotnetOpenAuth scopes and claims

Tags: asp.net-web-api, oauth-2.0, dotnetopenauth

I'm building an `ASP.NET Web Api` with `OAuth2 authorization` and am working on a application where we've got:

- Customers
- Organisations
- Users

*A customer has one or more organisations and a user can act for one or more customers.*

I want to make this logic a part of the scopes and accesstokens. This way I can restrict access but I also take some off the (complex) logic away from the application using my API. (When they chose a small scope)

**The scopes**

- Organisation
- Customer
- All

**For example**

> when a application requests an accesstoken with the **Organisation**
>   scope the user should see two dropdown boxes on the grant page. One to
>   select a Customer and a second to select one off the Organisations
>   this customer has.
>
> This way the accesstoken with scope organisation should be restricted to just the data off this single Organisation.

**What would be the best way to realise this using `DotNetOpenAuth`?**

Should I add the organisationId and customerId as scopes to the accesstoken? And if I do so how would I handle the 'Customer' scope? Should I just add the CustomerId without a organisation id? (Customers can have up to around 150 organisations)

Ideal I would like to transform this into Claims wich I can easy use to authorize the users actions.

I would like some feedback if scopes are the right way to fix this or some ideas how I could better fix this, without reinventing the wheel or breaking the DotNetOpenAuth framework open.

**PS**
I build both the `AuthorizationServer` and the `ResourceServer`.

Answer (score 1):

You should not add the organisation ID as far as I'm concerned. You should just consider the token as a proof that the user is able to *access* organisations, not *which* organisations specifically. The server can use the username stored in the token to display only those organisations the user is allow to see. In other words, there are now two checks the server needs to do:

1. The server checks if the token provided is authorized for the **Organisation** scope.
2. The server checks which specific organisations the user (which is retrieved from the token) is authorized for.

That way you can keep your OAuth scopes plain and simple, but you are still able to restrict access to only specific organisations.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! The problem is that one user can have access to multiple organisations. The token in this case is proof that the user granted the application to access that specific resource.

Comment: Yes, but the server can check that right? It doesn't have to be contained in the token.

Comment: I've been thinking about your solution (that's why I didn't reply instantly) but I just don't see how this would fit. The server that does the authorization and authentication (and generates tokens) is a different server/database then the server that is used by the API. The API just expects a token, tries to transform the token into Claims and that's all the API is aware off if it comes to security. If you look at the DotNetOpenAuth framework i also see no 'build in' /'good' way to save a relation between a token and what the token gives access to. If i'm wrong, please correct me :)